# How to set the maximum and minimum limit for a variable in C?

Tags: c

1. If I want to set a int variable which is "larger or equal to 100" and "smaller or equal to 200", how do I do that?
2. I heard it is like "char a[1024]" if I want to set maximum string length to 1024 but how to set minimum string length?

Comment: 1. C's type system does not provide you tools for that

Comment: I suspect what you want is not possible, though if you clarify what exactly you want, people here might find a solution. You might want to add an example to your question and describe how you want your example to behave. You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: `char a[1024]` is an array of 1024 chars. In C, strings are `'\0'` terminated, meaning that even if there is a string terminator that makes said string smaller, the array is still 1024 chars large.

Comment: You may not limit a variable’s range on your own but you may enforce a range with your code i.e. `if(n < lbound || n > ubound) ...`

Comment: The answer to 1 is to use the [Ada programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)#Data_types).

Answer (score 1):

> 1.If I want to set a int variable which is "larger or equal to 100" and "smaller or equal to 200", how do I do that?

The range of a C integer object is set by constants of its type such as `INT_MIN, UCHAR_MAX, LLONG_MIN`.  There are not user selectable to 100 or 200.

> 2.I heard it is like "char a[1024]" if I want to set maximum string length to 1024 but how to set minimum string length?

First: off-by-1: the legitimate possible values from `strlen(a)` would be [0...1023], not 1024.

The minimum and maximum length is not controllable in C with an overall settable limit.  Code needs to be judiciously written to not attempt exceeding a destination array bounds (of 1023 + 1 for the *null character* in OP's example)

Code could use care in populating an array with various means.  If  destination array is insufficient, code will likely need to take a different path.

```
int len = snprintf(a, sizeof a, "%d %s", some_int, some_string);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof a) {
  puts("Encoding error, or buffer is too small");
  // Destination was likely too small.
}
```